# Can I use code generated by Dreamweaver within my mern stack apps?

Tags: reactjs, adobe, mern, dreamweaver

I want to buy Adobe's software, Dreamweaver. In my research in Google, they are saying that Dreamweaver can generate Html and css code by designing visually the website. It's like a wysiwyg but for websites. I want it to know if it's possible to use that code in my react apps?